# My homepage is gone but header is still there

Tags: pages, headers, 500-internal-error

I just updated a page on the website, not the homepage, and then clicked to view the change. It was fine, but when I clicked to navigate to the homepage the only thing that was showing was my header image. Menu and all home page content is not showing up, even though it is fine in the 'pages' section.  Now the other URLs aren't working either.

Here is my [Home Page](http://www.bodykneadspa.com) and the most recently adjusted [page](http://www.bodykneadspa.com/specials).

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is to enable WP_DEBUG and see if you get any errors https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I get a 500 status code from your server, you likely have a PHP fatal error, please refer to your error log and take debugging steps to find out what the error message is

Comment: Thank you.  I will.  In the mean time I did some trouble shooting with the plugins page and it turns out the 'sitemap' plugin may be the culprit.  It works fine after I deactivated that plugin.  I will definitely debug however.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

jjj reported that the issue has been solved in the comments to the original question:

> ...In the mean time I did some trouble shooting with the plugins page
>   and it turns out the 'sitemap' plugin may be the culprit. It works
>   fine after I deactivated that plugin. I will definitely debug however.
>   Thank you again